# Нужно ли обособление оборотов с "как" и "словно"?

Tags: пунктуация, как, сравнительный-оборот

1. **Кобыла была резвой() как пылающий огонь костра.**
2. **От яркого света солнца Евгений на минуту ослеп() словно крот.**

Мне кажется, запятая в обоих предложениях нужна, ведь ни ***как***, ни ***словно*** не являются частями своих сказуемых, и эти обороты не имеют значения приравнивания/отождествления. Где истина?

Comment: Мои сомнения обусловлены тем, что эти предложения приведены в качестве примера автором, написавшим материал, касающийся русского языка. Автор не поставил запятых.

Comment: Мои сомнения обусловлены тем, что эти предложения приведены в качестве примера автором, написавшим материал, касающийся русского языка. Запятые автором проигнорированы.

Comment: Фразы эти вырваны из контекста — если он вообще есть — и гиперболы в сравнениях, в них содержащиеся, не просто необычны, а неадекватны. Видимо, русский автору не родной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, Вы абсолютно правы. Запятые нужны, так как они выделяют сравнительный оборот.

Кобыла была резвой, как пылающий огонь костра.
От яркого света солнца Евгений на минуту ослеп, словно крот.

Answer (score 3):

1. **Кобыла была резвой, как пылающий огонь костра.**

Классический сравнительный оборот как по смыслу, так и по интонации. Правда, метафора (резвый огонь) довольно смелая.

2. **От яркого света солнца Евгений на минуту ослеп, словно крот.**

Это тоже сравнительный оборот, но здесь возможны интонационные варианты. Если пауза не делается, то запятая ставится согласно только грамматическому принципу.

С другой стороны, вызывает сомнение выражение "ослеп, словно крот". Кроты практически ничего не видят от природы, они не могу ослепнуть. Правильнее было бы сказать "стал слепым, словно крот". Тогда  оборот интонационно выделяется в большей степени:

**От яркого света солнца Евгений на минуту стал слепым, словно крот.**